# Convergence to zero of exponential map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, exponential-function

Let $A$ be some matrix and for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have for

$$x(t):=e^{At}x$$ that $\frac{d}{dt}||x(t)||<0$ if $x$ was not zero.

Then I was wondering if we can conclude that $||x(t)|| \rightarrow 0$ exponentially fast, that is:

For $||x|| \le 1$:
$$||x(t)||\le \beta e^{-\alpha t}$$ for some $\beta>0,\alpha>0.$

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A$ has an eigenvalue $a+b\,i$ with $a$, $b$ reals and $a\ge0$, and let $u+i\,v$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then
$$
x(t)=e^{(a+bi)t}(u+i\,v)
$$
is a (complex valued) solution whose norm
$$
\|x(t)\|=e^{at}\|u+iv\|
$$does not decrease. Hence, all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part. This implies that the inequality holds with $\alpha$ smaller that the minimum of the absolute value of the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$. In fact, the following inequality will hold:
$$
\|x(t)\|\le C\,e^{-\alpha t}\,\|x(0)\|,\quad t>0,
$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: and where does this constant come from? I feel that you have to take somehow the fact into account that $A$ is not necessary diagonalisable, maybe that's why, but I don't know.

Comment: Even if $A$ is diagonalisable there may be a constant (the $\beta$ in your formulation.)

Comment: What I am asking is: How do you come from the fact that all eigenvalues are negative, to the last inequality.

Comment: The solution will be a combination of functions of the form $t^ke^{(a+bi)t}\,V$ for some vector $V$.

Comment: so you are using something like Jordan decomposition and this t^k comes from the nilpotent part?

Comment: Yes, trata is Noé of the standard aya of cómputo global the matriz exponential.

Comment: @ Julián Aguirre , you assume that the hypothesis works for every choice of $x=x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: My previous comment was corrupted by the spelling software. While I was writing in english, it was trying to convert it into spanish. Using the Jordan cannonical form is the standard way to compute the matrix exponential and solve linear systems of ODE's with constants coefficients. And yes, the ineqiality holds for any initial value $x(0)=x_0$.